# javascript mysql and promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with promises, or at least trying to.

Here is what my code look's so far:

```
checkEmailUsername = function(mail, user) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var query;
      query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? OR username = ?";
      return connection.query(query, [mail, user], function(err, row, fields) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        console.log(row.length);
        if (row.length > 0) {
          return resolve(true);
        } else {
          return resolve(false);
        }
      });
    }).then()["catch"]();
  };
```

Question is. How to return the resolve values from inside the promise?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use return here, use the promise resolve function to return the rows from db to the caller.

```
checkEmailUsername = function (mail, user) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var query;
        query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? OR username = ?";
        connection.query(query, [mail, user], function (err, row, fields) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            console.log(row.length);
            resolve(row);
        });
    };

    checkEmailUsername(mail, user).then(function (rows) {
        // do something with the rows
    }).catch((err) => {
        //handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: Why i can't console.log checkEmailUsername return? now im returning the value from inside .then() function

Comment: You can't return things from asynchronous code, the result is not ready when you are trying to log it, and the program continues to next line. You can log it inside the 'then', when the promise is resolved already.